# RDB data combination table modeling

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms

There's data and if I combine it, I need to get the corresponding result.

If I choose A and I got B,

If I choose B, I should also get A.

I want to save both data and combinations in DB, but it's hard to organize the table.

**Example**

```
DATA: A, B, C, D, E, F, G

choose A → got B, C
choose B → got A, E
choose A, E → got F, G
choose F, G → got A, E
choose D, E, F → got C
```

**Extra Explain**

If I want this combinations

A, B, C -> B

A -> B

B -> A

I design database like this but I don't think it's a good way, so I'm asking.

**data table**

```
| id | data |
|----|------|
|  1 |  A   |
|  2 |  B   |
|  3 |  C   |
```

**combination table**

```
| id | entry   | output |
|----|---------|--------|
| 1  | '1,2,3' | '2'    |
| 2  | '1'     | '2'    |
| 3  | '2'     | '1'    |
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community, Please try to clarify your question by adding more information, your current table schema, how data should be selected, etc. If you don't, it will be probably closed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.